# How to fetch both parent and child from same hierarchical table, from one value, which may be parent or child?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following tables:

**Table: Category**

```
CategoryID int identity PK <--.
ParentID int NULL FK --->-----'
Name varchar(50)
```

It allows a parent/child relationship in the same table:

```
CategoryID   ParentID   Name
--------------------------------
1            NULL       Parent A
2            1          Child A
```

**Table: Project**

```
ProjectID int identity PK
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
```

I also have a junction table for projects and categories

**Table: ProjectCategory**

```
ProjectID int PK FK
CategoryID int PK FK

ProjectID    CategoryID
--------------------------------
1            2 <-- Either a parent or child category
```

A project can be assigned to either a parent category, or a child category, but not both. In essence, if a project is assigned to a child category, it's relationally tied to the parent category regardless, and I don't want this:

```
ProjectID    CategoryID
--------------------------------
1            1 <-- Parent
1            2 <-- Child of Parent 1
```

That's all fine, but for my application I need to flatten things out and have a result set/row that looks like this:

```
ProjectID    ParentCategoryID   ChildCategoryID
-----------------------------------------------
1            1                  2
```

So the issue is, I'm not sure of the best way to provide both for the application, but it needs to be done in a single SQL query that results in a single row of data.

**Update**

I posted an answer to myself, but please tear it apart if there's a better way.

Comment: Is it not possible to have grandchildren or deeper parent-child relationships?

Comment: Basically no, not yet. The explanation of the application is what enforces this right now, but because this rule may change in the future is why I have it setup that way in the DB.

Comment: @Anand, I've updated my question in attempts to simplify. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found my own answer, but I'll quickly take a better one if there's a better way.

```
SELECT p.*
      ,ISNULL(cat.ParentID, cat.CategoryID) AS ParentCategoryID
      ,CASE WHEN cat.ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN cat.CategoryID
       END ChildCategoryID

FROM Project p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 c.CategoryID, c.ParentID FROM ProjectCategory pc
    INNER JOIN Category c ON c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID
    WHERE pc.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
) cat
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have self referential foreign key on Category table from ParentID to CategoryID. You are really complicating things in your description, since the ParentID will also exist as a CategoryID, all you need is a simple join between the two tables:

```
select pc.ProjectID,
       coalesce(c.ParentID, c.CategoryID) as ParentCategoryID --shows category id as parent if it has no parent
       case when c.ParentID is not null then c.CategoryID end as ChildCategoryID
from   ProjectCategory as pc
inner  join Category as c
on     c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID
```

Comment: In your example, if c.ParentID is null, this seems to fail. I need to get the ParentID if it isn't the ParentID to begin with. Please see my answer as an example where I'm using `ISNULL()`. It's possible I overcomplicated things for sure. I'll update my question and try to clear out some of the muck. Thank you @Anand for your help.

Comment: I think you mean, it should show you the category as it's own parent if it has no parent? If so, edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. My brain is tied up after staring at this. You still have to deal with `ChildCategoryID` though, right? Like in my answer? Otherwise `ChildCategoryID` may actually be a parent.

Comment: Other than that, the difference seems to be a JOIN vs OUTER APPLY. I'm not a pro at performance testing in SQL. The TOP 1 in my example is superfluous. My data was a bit of a mess when testing.

Comment: Lol, you are further confusing yourself :) If the child category is a parent, then it will show up in it's child's row as the parent.

Comment: Haha, no. I have a limit in the application layer. I can't allow a column called `ChildCategoryID` to be a parent. Or am I still confused?

Comment: I think we have a gap in understanding; I'm not proposing that the ChildCategoryID ***will*** show up in the ParentCategoryID column. If you are preventing that from happening from the application layer, that is fine. I'm saying that the query doesn't need to account for that (it will only show the data that exists). Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143218/discussion-between-user1447679-and-anand).

Comment: No problem. The issue is, the ChildCategoryID column cannot represent the ParentCategoryID, which in your example allows for. Your JOIN doesn't enforce that the join is on a "parent" or "child" category. If you see my answer, the only way ChildCategoryID gets a value is if it has a parent value.

Comment: I get it, you want to show a category as parent when it is parent as opposed to a child. Revised the answer again.